# Any plans for a new theme?

Tags: discussion, design

Writers SE could do with a theme refresh.
Are there any plans on the table?

And why does this keep telling my question doesn't meet quality standards?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Will we get fancy site design like Math.SE and English.SE?](http://meta.writers.stackexchange.com/questions/75/will-we-get-fancy-site-design-like-math-se-and-english-se)

Comment: A relevant post (on this meta) by one of our Community Managers from last week: [Custom Writing design and logo - Information gathering](https://writing.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2492/24064) :)

Comment: Update: [Your new site design is live!](https://writing.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2566/24064)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If by theme you mean the design, we get a real design that is specific to the site when we leave beta.  So invite your writer friends, share the questions on facebook and twitter, ask questions, answer questions, and vote to get us there!

Your questions are auto-marked by the system as low quality if they meet some of the criteria discussed in this [system-wide meta question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/56817/can-we-prevent-some-of-the-low-quality-questions-from-entering-our-system/60294#60294)

Comment: Is there any pre-existing themes with a serif body font that we can used while still in beta?

Comment: @HNL - the theme is what it is.  If you want to talk to the designer about it, [Jin Yang](http://stackexchange.com/users/21721/jin) is your contact.